# JPA - Default value

Tags: jpa, insert, eclipselink

I am developing an JPA application, and I'm using eclipse link provider.

I've a table T1 that has a field F1 defined as not null and with a default value ('U').

I've defined an entity mapped to the table T1. The entity has an attribute mapped to the field F1, and I have configured the attribute with the annotation @ReturnInsert(returnOnly = true).

Documentation says:

> Use @ReturnInsert to cause INSERT operations to return values back into the object being written

If I persist an entity with no value in the attribute mapped to F1, everything works fine. The entity is automatically populate with the default value after the insert, and a record is inserted in database.

But if I try to persist an entity with a different value (no default value), a record is inserted into database, but the value of field F1 is the default value, when it should be the value I set in the entity.

Why is happening this? All I want is to change the default value.

Thanks

Comment: What happens if you issue an insert to the database through JDBC or a database tool and include a value for the field? Try turning on EclipseLink logging to see the statement it issues for the insert, and issue that SQL to your db directly.

Comment: If I do an insert to the database through a databasetool including a value for the field, the insert is done right. If I turn on EclipseLink logging, I can see that insert is not right at all, as the field annotated with @ReturnInsert is not included. The insert is something like: "INSERT INTO t1 (F2, F3) VALUES ('value1', 'value2') RETURNING F1 INTO ?. Because F1 is not included, the default value is not overrided.

Answer (score 0):

What I did to have default value for a field in my database was:

1. Define a default value for that field in database
2. Make the corresponding attribute in your entity to read-only.

for example for a Date field you can do like this:

**in DB:**

```
reg_date    DATE NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE
```

**in Entity:**

```
@Basic(optional=false)
@Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
@Column(name = "reg_date", insertable= false)
private Date regDate;
```

By doing this I got a field that always be automatically set by database when a new field inserted.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've tried exactly what you have told me but it doesn't work. I'm receiving a java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL.

Comment: @Eduardo what's your db? I tested with PostgreSQL and it worked. but JPA and DB are not that match. I had problem with setting another field to default value and then I decided to ignore DB's default and place the default values in *entity constructor*s.

Comment: My DB is Oracle and I'm using eclipselink provider. I've read that there is a bug and insertable= false only works if updatable is also false. I've found solutions like the one you propose me (entity constructor), but I don't like at all because if someone change the default value in DB, I should remember to change also the default value in the program code.